# Google Analytics Report get all result instead of only filtered event category

Tags: google-analytics

This is screenshot from analytics report:
[Analytics Report Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oX4wV.png)

When I try to use google analytics report php api (v.2.2.2) with the filter event Category (filtered by "Videos" category):

```
$dateRange = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_DateRange();
$dateRange->setStartDate("3daysago");
$dateRange->setEndDate("today");


// Create the Metrics object.
$ev = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Metric();
$ev->setExpression("ga:eventValue");
$ev->setAlias("EventValue");

$tEv = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Metric();
$tEv->setExpression("ga:totalEvents");
$tEv->setAlias("Total Events");

$avg = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Metric();
$avg->setExpression("ga:avgEventValue");
$avg->setAlias("Avg Value");

//Create the dimensions
// $sc = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Dimension();
// $sc->setName("ga:subContinent");

$ec = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Dimension();
$ec->setName("ga:eventCategory");

$ea = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Dimension();
$ea->setName("ga:eventAction");

$el = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Dimension();
$el->setName("ga:eventLabel");


// Create the segment dimension.
$segmentDimensions = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Dimension();
$segmentDimensions->setName("ga:segment");

// Create Dimension Filter.
$dimensionFilter = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_SegmentDimensionFilter();
$dimensionFilter->setDimensionName("ga:eventCategory");
$dimensionFilter->setOperator("EXACT");
$dimensionFilter->setExpressions(array("Videos"));

// Create Segment Filter Clause.
$segmentFilterClause = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_SegmentFilterClause();
$segmentFilterClause->setDimensionFilter($dimensionFilter);

// Create the Or Filters for Segment.
$orFiltersForSegment = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_OrFiltersForSegment();
$orFiltersForSegment->setSegmentFilterClauses(array($segmentFilterClause));

// Create the Simple Segment.
$simpleSegment = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_SimpleSegment();
$simpleSegment->setOrFiltersForSegment(array($orFiltersForSegment));

// Create the Segment Filters.
$segmentFilter = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_SegmentFilter();
$segmentFilter->setSimpleSegment($simpleSegment);

// Create the Segment Definition.
$segmentDefinition = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_SegmentDefinition();
$segmentDefinition->setSegmentFilters(array($segmentFilter));

// Create the Dynamic Segment.
$dynamicSegment = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_DynamicSegment();
$dynamicSegment->setSessionSegment($segmentDefinition);
$dynamicSegment->setName("Video");

// Create the Segments object.
$segment = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Segment();
$segment->setDynamicSegment($dynamicSegment);


// Create the ReportRequest object.
$request = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_ReportRequest();
$request->setViewId($VIEW_ID);
$request->setDateRanges(array($dateRange));
$request->setSegments(array($segment));
$request->setDimensions(array($segmentDimensions,$ec,$ea,$el));
$request->setMetrics(array($ev, $avg, $tEv));

// Create the GetReportsRequest object.
$getReport = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_GetReportsRequest();
$getReport->setReportRequests(array($request));

// Call the batchGet method.
$body = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_GetReportsRequest();
$body->setReportRequests( array( $request) );
$response = $analyticsreporting->reports->batchGet( $body );

printResults($response->getReports());
```

And the result return all categories (Banner and Videos):

```
ga:segment: Video
ga:eventCategory: Banner
ga:eventAction: click
ga:eventLabel: click on banner
EventValue: 0
Avg Value: 0.0
Total Events: 52
----------------------------
ga:segment: Video
ga:eventCategory: Videos
ga:eventAction: play
ga:eventLabel: Fall Campaign
EventValue: 0
Avg Value: 0.0
Total Events: 29
```

I'm a beginer on this, can you show me what's my problem?

./Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be creating a segment not a filter. You want to change your code to use Filters instead. Filters will only show you the data that matches the filter, while a segment will create a slice of all GA sessions that had at least one event with category Video. If other events were also present in the same sessions they would be included in the segment.

A good way to think about it is that segments only filter whole sessions and Filters can slice the actual returned data for the specific API call.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Eduardo. That great, I got it.